# Use TypeScript Type support with Underscore

Tags: typescript

I do want use Type checking within undescore 'where' methods on some semi-complex model. Like for example:

```
class User {
    public name: string;
    public age: number;
    public someOtherProperty: any;
}
```

And I have list of such moders called **users**

Now I want to get all users with name 'John', with underscore method 'where'

```
public getAllJohns():Array<User> {
    return _.where<User, any>(this.users, {
        name: 'John'
    });
}
```

And that is ok, but why I have to drop Type Guard? It pretty nice to get error, when I write accidently

```
public getAllJohns():Array<User> {
    return _.where<User, any>(this.users, {
        names: 'John'
    });
}
```

Creating list of interfaces for second 'generic' argument in where, like

```
interface byName {
    name: string;
}
```

Is not a solution, since there will be many diffrent methods with diffrent list of required property to check.

So.. does anyone have a nice solution for this, or it is more someting which should go to TypeScript team like a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll do need some of kind type specified for the second argument of the `where` method if you'd wish to keep type safety. This can be an [inline interface](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces), but that doesn't really get you anywhere.

If you are only concerned about having to need numerous combinations of members of a given type, you could use an interface with [optional members](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-optional-properties):

```
interface IUser {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    someOtherProperty?: any;
}
```

After which it is a trivial one:

```
public getAllJohns(): Array<User> {
    return _.where<User, IUser>(this.users, {
        names: 'John' // Error: Property 'names' does not exist on type 'IUser'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is an object with some of the keys defined in the User interface, right? So would it be appropriate to build some query interfaces with exactly the same keys / types but optional fields?

```
class UserCondition {
    public name?: string;
    public age?: number;
    public someOtherProperty?: any;
}
```

Together with the strict object literal checking (aka Freshness, https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html), this could help make your queries more typesafe.

```
public getAllJohns():Array<User> {
    return _.where<User, UserCondition>(this.users, {
        name: 'John'
    });
}
```